# Postgres update from large table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a Postgres 12 table with more than 20 million rows (the table is partitioned on the customer_column_id) called A and I also have a table with 2.2 million rows called B. I want to update B by selecting data from A but it sometimes is taking 3 minutes and sometimes throwing an exception while reading from stream or the operation times out. The query which I am using is below.

```
UPDATE B 
  set "udd_erhvervsfaglig_forloeb" = A.value 
from A 
where A.customer_column_id = 60 
  and B.customer_id = A.customer_id 
  and coalesce(A.value, '') != ''
```

Query Plan

````
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..15739311932.47 rows=6273088796225 width=85506)
        ->  Seq Scan on B(cost=0.00..3509632.93 rows=112625893 width=84980)
        ->  Index Scan using A_66_customer_id_idx1 on A_66 cev  (cost=0.43..0.46 rows=1 width=17)
              Index Cond: (customer_id = B.customer_id)
              Filter: (((COALESCE(value, ''::character varying))::text <> ''::text) AND (customer_column_id = 66))```
````

Comment: `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "cev"`

Comment: Ask the database about the query plan, using EXPLAIN: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/using-explain.html Could you show us the result?

Comment: @jjanes I have edited the question cev was actually table A.

Comment: @FrankHeikens  (cost=0.00..9764151.42 rows=453842028 width=24) here is the query plan.

Comment: That's only one row of the query plan, but at least it tells us that the database thinks it has to update over 45 million records. Does that make sense to you? And do you have an index on B.customer_id  and A.customer_column_id ? You could also analyse your query plan at https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: @FrankHeikens Update on B  (cost=0.43..15739311932.47 rows=6273088796225 width=85506)
Filter: (((COALESCE(value, ''::character varying))::text <> ''::text) AND (customer_column_id = 66))
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..15739311932.47 rows=6273088796225 width=85506)
        ->  Seq Scan on B dyn  (cost=0.00..3509632.93 rows=112625893 width=84980)
        ->  Index Scan using A_66_customer_id_idx1 on A_66 cev  (cost=0.43..0.46 rows=1 width=17)
Index Cond: (customer_id = B.customer_id)
Filter: (((COALESCE(value, ''::character varying))::text <> ''::text) AND (customer_column_id = 66))

Comment: @FrankHeikens previous was wrong it is the actual query plan.

Comment: And yes I have indexes on A.customer_column_id and B.customer_id.

Comment: It's now even worse, the database expects 6273088796225 records for this update. That doesn't sound right, or does it? Did you ANALYZE your database or table? And next time, could you put the query plan in the original question or at explain.depesz.com That makes it more readable

Comment: @FrankHeikens yes because table is a very large table and it is partitioned I have checked the query plan for one of it's partition it says it has to update over 112062767 records. Also, I putted the original query plan.

Comment: When I use explain to select all data from table A it says 454085398 records and when I use explain to select all data from one of its partitions it says 11195670 records.

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE? And put the results in your original question or on https://explain.depesz.com so we can see the whole plan. And 6 trillion records, are you really sure about that? It would be amazing if a database could update so many records in 3 minutes

Comment: @FrankHeiken I have added the query plan in the question and yes it is I am sure that the data table has is more. Moreover, the update of 3 minutes is not on table A it's on table B which has 2.2 million records also, but for updating table B it has to fetch records from table A which has more data.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of avoiding nested loops could be using EXISTS. So, your query can be written like this:

```
UPDATE B 
   SET "udd_erhvervsfaglig_forloeb" = A.value 
  FROM A 
 WHERE  
  EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM a
           WHERE B.customer_id = A.customer_id
             AND A.customer_column_id = 60
             AND coalesce(A.value, '') != '');
```

Comment: Tried it out on test data, but not on 20M rows)

Comment: It's not working in my scenario it is taking a lot of time.

Comment: Yes, it will go row by row, not the fast one